# Setting security zones via pac while proxying with FiddlerCore

Tags: security, internet-explorer, fiddler, zones

Is there any way to have a pac file properly set zones in IE while capturing traffic with FiddlerCore?  When I use FiddlerCore with a pac, everything ends up in the default zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you're asking: "*Can I have a PAC script that returns DIRECT such that traffic is Zoned into the Intranet Zone but still goes through FiddlerCore*?"

Traffic can't both bypass FiddlerCore (to get Intranet Zone) and simultaneously be sent to FiddlerCore (to get captured). You *can* however, use the manual Zone settings to map sites to the Intranet zone if you'd like. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/05/the-local-intranet-security-zone.aspx for more information.